ZIO: union 3 Console effects
I'm trying to realise effect, which consequently union 3 effects: print to console, read this value and then print this value to console.
My code:
  object ZioMain extends ZIOAppDefault {
     override def run: IO[IOException, Unit]= { 
          def printReadPrint(): IO[IOException, Unit] = Console.print("Message")
                                                             .flatMap(_ => Console.readLine)
                                                             .flatMap(v = >Console.print(v))
        printReadPrint()
       }
    }

So, I expected, output will be:
 Message
 Message

But in fact I see only one "Message" record in Console
 Message

What am I doing wrong?

Why did you expect two Message? Because that is what you read? Also, where are you using printReadPrint?

readLine reads a line from the console from user input. It doesn't read the last line you printed to the console.

Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, I expect second "Message", because Console.readLine return IO[IOException, String], and following flatMap should extract String-value from this IO. And I expected, this extracted string value to be passed in Console.print as argument.

Gaël J, ok, readLine read the user input. But why then it does not pass it to the following flatMap(v = >Console.print(v)) ?

@Jelly are you sure is not just that you passed an empty string? Also, since I would assume there is a println version and you are using print you would not even see a new line in the case of an empty string, just nothing.

May be what you are looking for is some kind of utility that reads every new line and does processing on it. ZStream is a good abstraction tool for handling sequence of data and there is even an example how to use it for reading a line - https://zio.dev/reference/stream/zstream/creating-zio-streams#from-zio

@Jelly from your code it seems like you want to read from console and write it to console as well, you can try ZStream create a Console Source process it via ZPipeline and Create a ZSink and will write it to console, as already suggested by Lachezar
As a reference you can take a look on this https://github.com/ramanmishra/humidity-sensor-app, this app reads from csv and writes it to console.
